# Implement zoom functionality on Canvas rect using move and resize

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need to implement zoom in zoom out functionality with rectangle draw on canvas, the algorithm like there are few rectangle in the canavs and when mouse scroll up it need to scroll, for this first I move the rectangle towards left/right/up/down based on the mouse position and then increases width and size of rect and then draw it.

With current method there few problem like when rectangle overlap it not work properly. Or with the current algorithm seems not perfect.

I need do the zoom features with two action one is resize and another move, and used should feel the zooming effect.

Can anyone suggest some improvement in current method or new method.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var zoomStep = 10;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = parseInt(event.clientX - rect.left);
  var y = parseInt(event.clientY - rect.top);

  win.push({ x: x, y: y, width: 75, height: 35});
  drawAll();
})
canvas.onmousewheel = function(event) {
  var wheel = event.wheelDelta / 120; //n or -n
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = parseInt(event.clientX - rect.left);
  var y = parseInt(event.clientY - rect.top);
  var zoom = 0;
  if (wheel < 0) {
    zoomOut(x, y);
  } else {
    zoomIn(x, y);
  }
}

var win = [];
win.push({ x: 300, y: 300, width: 75, height: 35 });
win.push({ x: 400, y: 400, width: 75, height: 35 });
drawAll();


function drawAll() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  for (var i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {
    var shape = win[i];
    ctx.strokeRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, shape.height);
  }
}

function zoomOut(mouse_x, mouse_y) {
  console.log(mouse_x, mouse_y)

  for (var i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {
    //window before mouse x
    if (win[i].x + win[i].width < mouse_x) {
      win[i].x = win[i].x + zoomStep;
    }
    //window after mouse x
    else if (win[i].x >= mouse_x) {
      win[i].x = win[i].x - zoomStep;
    }
    //window overlap mouse_x
    else {

    }

    //window before mouse y
    if (win[i].y + win[i].height < mouse_y) {
      win[i].y = win[i].y + zoomStep;
    }
    //window after mouse y
    else if (win[i].y >= mouse_y) {
      win[i].y = win[i].y - zoomStep;
    }
    //window overlap mouse_y
    else {

    }

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {
    win[i].width = win[i].width - zoomStep;
    win[i].height = win[i].height - zoomStep;
  }
  drawAll();
}

function zoomIn(mouse_x, mouse_y) {

  console.log(mouse_x, mouse_y)

  for (var i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {
    //window before mouse x
    if (win[i].x + win[i].width < mouse_x) {
      win[i].x = win[i].x - zoomStep;
    }
    //window after mouse x
    else if (win[i].x >= mouse_x) {
      win[i].x = win[i].x + zoomStep;
    }
    //window overlap mouse_x
    else {

    }

    //window before mouse y
    if (win[i].y + win[i].height < mouse_y) {
      win[i].y = win[i].y - zoomStep;
    }
    //window after mouse y
    else if (win[i].y >= mouse_y) {
      win[i].y = win[i].y + zoomStep;
    }
    //window overlap mouse_y
    else {

    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {
    win[i].width = win[i].width + zoomStep;
    win[i].height = win[i].height + zoomStep;
  }

  drawAll();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation delete those zoom functions and start from scratch.
You are doing something but certainly not zoom...

Start shapes:
[image]

After a few zoom:
[image]

Obvious problems:

- the rectangles are moving relative to each other
- the shape is changing, they look more like squares

---

You might want to read about translate and transform:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform